# Problema con JButtton actualizar MySQL

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mvc

Tengo este método para actualizar los elementos de una tabla en una clase que se encarga de controlar los eventos de los **Jframe**:

```
    if(e.getSource()== estMostrar.getBtnModificar()){
        int fila= estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante().getSelectedRow();

        if(fila>=0){
        String nombre= estMostrar.getTxtNombre().getText();
        String materia= estMostrar.getTxtMatricula().getText();
        String nota= estMostrar.getTxtNota().getText();

        List<Estudiante> estudiantes = estDAO.extraerTodos();
        Estudiante es = estudiantes.get(fila);

            if(es!=null){
                int id = es.getId(); 
                this.estDAO.actualizar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)), id);

                this.LimpiarCampos();
                this.estMostrar.dispose();
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(estAdmin, "Seleccione Estudiante");
            }
                this.ListarTabla(estAdmin.getTablaEstudiante());
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(estAdmin, "No ha selecionado fila");
        }
    }
```

El método de arriba envía los datos como parámetros al siguiente método para actualizar el objeto en la **Base de datos**:

```
public void actualizar(Estudiante e, int Id) {
    Connection con= null;
    PreparedStatement pstm= null;

        try {
            con= dbcon.conectar();

            String sql= "UPDATE notas SET nombre= ?, matricula= ?, nota= ?"
                    + "WHERE id = ?";
            pstm= con.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstm.setString(1, e.getNombre());
            pstm.setString(2, e.getMatricula());
            pstm.setInt(3, e.getNota());
            pstm.setInt(4, Id);

            pstm.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al conectar a la BD");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            dbcon.desconectar(con);
    }
}
```

Cuando intento actualizar un elemento, me da un error en consola, este es el **stackTrace:**

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = 1' at line 1
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:387)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:942)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2673)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
at comm.estudiante.dao.mysql.EstudianteDAOImpl.actualizar(EstudianteDAOImpl.java:115)
at comm.estudiante.dao.controlador.ControladorEstudiante.actionPerformed(ControladorEstudiante.java:241)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

La línea numero 115 que dice el **stackTrace** corresponde al **actualizar(Estudiante e, int Id)** es la siguiente:

```
pstm.executeUpdate();
```

Y la siguiente es la línea 241 que menciona el **stackTrace** corresponde al **if** del botón modificar, que esta al principio:

```
this.estDAO.actualizar(new Estudiante(nombre, materia, Integer.parseInt(nota)), id);
```

Realmente no se que sucede pues, el método recibe el **id** del objeto.

Comment: David cual es la estructura de tu tabla?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es indicado aqui :

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id = 1' at line
>   1

y es debido a que en tu Query es incorrecto ya que el valor de `nota` esta junto a la palabra `"WHERE"`:

```
 String sql= "UPDATE notas SET nombre= ?, matricula= ?, nota= ?"
                    + "WHERE id = ?";
```

Necesitas agregar un espacio antes de la palabra `"WHERE"` :

```
String sql= "UPDATE notas SET nombre= ?, matricula= ?, nota= ?"
                    + " WHERE id = ?";
```

Comment: Toda la razón @Elenasys, tantas veces que revisé la consulta y no me percaté, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Como buena practica al tener este tipo de problema es imprimir la consulta contenida en la variable "sql", de esta forma puedes encontrar rapidamente el problema, saludos!

Comment: No lo había pensado, lo tendré presente para una próxima ocasión, nuevamente gracias por la ayuda con la consulta y ahora por este consejo